# Symfony 4.3 + ApiPlatform + Accept-Language

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have just started with Api Platform and I have a problem with translating validator's messages.

I've:

...created two files with translations: /translations/validators.en.yaml and /translations/validators.fr.yaml

...added apropriate custom validator message

...set default_locale as *en*

...added translation validator definition in Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="test.message")
 */
private $title;
```

After that my custom translated message is returned correctly.

Now I want to enable translation relying on Accept-Language header instead of default_locale.

I know that symfony does not relay on Accept-Language header. Instead of that I created subscriber which is responsible for determining preferred language (from Accept-Language):

```php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class LocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $locale = substr($request->getPreferredLanguage(), 0, 2);

        $request->setDefaultLocale($locale);
        $request->setLocale($locale);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
           'kernel.request' => 'onKernelRequest',
        ];
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly this way doesn't work. Translation still relay on `kernel.default_locale` even if I put 'fr' directly as parameter to setLocale and setDefaultLocale.

Does anybody know how to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the pervious answer, but there is an other problem: Browsers use a dash in locales, but Symfony uses underscores. Here is a complete solution:

```
// https://github.com/metaclass-nl/tutorial-api-platform/blob/chapter4-api/api/src/EventSubscriber/LocaleSubscriber.php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderUtils;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class LocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $accept_language = $request->headers->get("accept-language");
        if (empty($accept_language)) {
            return;
        }
        $arr = HeaderUtils::split($accept_language, ',;');
        if (empty($arr[0][0])) {
            return;
        }

        // Symfony expects underscore instead of dash in locale
        $locale = str_replace('-', '_', $arr[0][0]);

        $request->setLocale($locale);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            // must be registered before (i.e. with a higher priority than) the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [['onKernelRequest', 20]],
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Symfony documentation page:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html

I think your listener should have a higher priority (like 20) so it is loaded before the local listener.